# Problem using pgfplots (reading csv)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use `pgfplots` to make several graphs. However I can't manage to use it. It always shows me that the file that should have been created was not found. It certainly was not created.

Thats the used Code for it:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=.9\textwidth,
    height=.6\textwidth,
    xlabel={ $x [\si{m}]$}, 
    ylabel={$\cw (x)$}, 
    axis lines=left,
    ymin=-0,
    ymax=3,
    ytick={0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3},
    xmax=35,
    xtick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed, %gestrichelte ticks linien
    legend pos=north west,
    %xticklabel style={anchor=south}, %x-Achse Zahlen oben oder unten
    axis x line=center,
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
        anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=south,
    },
]

\addplot [
    color=blue!80,
    line width=1.5pt,
    %mark size=2.0pt,
    %mark=triangle*,
]
table [x=speed, y=hight, col sep=semicolon] {tikz/example.csv};
\addlegendentry{\footnotesize Speed over hight};

\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}
```

And in the text I'm using

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
               \input{tikz/example.tex}
               \caption{first graphic}
               \label{fig:excelexaample}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

My excel file looks like this:

[image]

Any IDEAS ? Thanks a lot

Comment: BTW, don't put the environment `figure` inside `center`. Environment `figure` is usually a floating environment and floats away. Also it resets many things at the beginning of the float, thus the outside `center` does not have an effect. It's better to use `\centering` at the begin of the `figure`.

Comment: What happens if you try `\addplot[<all your options>] table [<table options>] {example.csv};`, i.e. without the `tikz/`. (By the way, a screenshot of Excel is totally irrelevant here, it doesn't say much about what the `.csv` file looks like or where it is located.)

Comment: A complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be nice. Where are the files `example.tex` and `example.csv` relative to the current directory, where the LaTeX job is running?

Comment: Yes it was running well, but since the graphics (made up with matlab) dont look that great in latex. I wanted to try it that way

Comment: Files are in a directory ( tikz)

Comment: BTW Im working on a MWE.

Comment: For lack of an MWE, could you post the actual CSV file, instead of the screenshot, and also post the complete error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't post the error you receive nor the contents of the csv file it is hard to guess what is happening.

In any case, the with the line `table [x=speed, y=hight, col sep=semicolon]` you are trying to plot a column named `hight` on the y axis versus a column named `speed` on the x axis. Therefore the csv file should have an header (first line) with column names but, looking at the excel screenshot, it seems that your file does not have such a line. Moreover, the third options tells  pgfplots that the columns in the file are separated by semicolons: it could be your case but I think is not the default for a csv file.